# Radcombobox with AllowCustomText = false and MarkFirstMatch = true not working properly in IE10

Tags: telerik, internet-explorer-10, radcombobox

it allows me to type only one letter, when typing a second letter it shows the options starting with this one. for  eg: when I type B it displays Black but if I type Bl it displays the L words eg: Layer, instead of keeping Black selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to be able to type down the text you should definitely enable "allowCustomText".
If you need to prevent then this text to be seen as data you should check manually that there is a selectedvalue.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: allowcustomtext set to false should allow me to type more than one character if the typed characters corresponds to an existing option in the radcombobox. I want to mention that this happens in mozzila and chrome but not in IE10 so It might be a telerik issue on IE10. :)